# Function only working for last call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a custom function in jQuery which is called loadFileList. It is supposed to gather some information about files on the server and display them into a div. It takes an ID list as parameter so it knows which files to display.

```
  $.fn.loadFileList = function($IDList){
    copy = $(this);
    $(this).html("");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://www.domain.com/index.php?action=getFileList",
        data: { IDs:$IDList }
        }).done(function( jsonList ) {
            files = JSON.parse(jsonList); 

            for(i=0; i < files.length; i++) {
                copy.append('<div class="file">'+ files[i].data.title +'</div>');
            }
        }); 
};
```

This function is globally stored in a js file called functions.js and the function itself is then called from an inline js in a webpage like this:

```
$("#file-container").loadFileList("55,80,21");
```

The problem now is if I want to add more than one file list for example

```
  $("#file-container-1").loadFileList("55,80,21");  
  $("#file-container-2").loadFileList("77,4");
```

only the last one is working. I am sure this is just a problem with references in jQuery but I just don't know how to solve it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are making `copy` a global variable meaning that keeps getting overwritten.

Comment: `copy` -> `var copy` should do it.

Comment: See difference between this http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/jgKA5/ and this http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/jgKA5/1/

Answer (score 0):

As Jason P mentioned as comment, you need to make the variable **local**.

Local means that the variable only exists within the function. You do this by declaring it in the function:

```
$.fn.loadFileList = function($IDList){
    var $copy = $(this);
    $copy.html(""); // refer to the variable, you've just selected it
};
```

In your current code the variable copy is global (document-wide). If one function changes the value, all others will use that same value, as if you defined it outside the function.

---

*Offtopic:

I took the liberty of renaming `copy` to `$copy`, it's someone common to define a jquery object to a variable with a `$` prepended, so you can tell the difference. Also, you might want to rename it to something like `$elem`, copy sounds a awefull lot like a function, that might confuse people.*

Comment: Does that mean you should rename $IDList to IDList?

Comment: Yes, because `IDlist` isn't a jQuery object, just a simple string